# categorical interpretation of the group generated by two subgoups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $H,K$ be two subgroups of a group $G$ and let $A=H\cap K$ and $B$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $H$ and $K$.
We know that
\begin{array}{rcl}
A & \rightarrow & H \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
K & \rightarrow & G
\end{array}
is a pull-back square (morphisms are inclusions).

Does there exists a similar interpretation for $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most blunt way of describing $\langle H \cup K \rangle \le G$ is as the image of the canonical homomorphism $H * K \to G$ (determined by the inclusions $H \hookrightarrow G, K \hookrightarrow G$), where $H * K$ denotes the coproduct (free product) of $H$ and $K$ as abstract groups.

This generalises readily to any cocomplete regular category and any small family of subobjects. (Exercise.)

Answer (score 4):

$H$ and $K$ are both objects in the category of [subobjects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subobject) of $G$. The category of subobjects is a preorder (exercise), so it behaves like a poset except that some objects are isomorphic. The categorical product in this category, which agrees with the pullback, is the intersection $H \cap K$, and the categorical coproduct in this category is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $H$ and $K$.

The [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject) asserts that in a topos, the coproduct of subobjects is their pushout along their product, but this is false for groups.